# Issues with Soundcloud iframe and YouTube iframe together

Tags: youtube-api, soundcloud, chromecast

The Soundcloud widget works fine playing multiple tracks in succession. If I then hide that frame, play a youtube video in a youtube iframe, and then switch back to a new track in the Soundcloud widget, it loads but will not play (ignoring the autoplay setting and any widget.play() calls). I had this working on Chromecast with the developer preview SDK and the 1.0 cast receiver but now with the 2.0.0 receiver it's broken. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: ok, got this working so hopefully this is useful to others. Assuming only one is active and visible at a time, the trick is to destroy the prior widgets rather than try to reuse them. 

For YouTube this does not mean reloading the iframe_api but simply calling YTPlayer.destroy() and new YT.Player() next time around.

For SoundCloud keep a handle of the iframe and then call iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe) to destroy and then create again next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got this working so hopefully this is useful to others. Assuming only one is active and visible at a time, the trick is to destroy the prior widgets rather than try to reuse them. For YouTube this does not mean reloading the iframe_api but simply calling YTPlayer.destroy() and new YT.Player() next time around. For SoundCloud keep a handle of the iframe and then call iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe) to destroy and then create again next time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no supported mechanism in the SDK to play YouTube videos outside of the YouTube app. Note that in general, applications may not allow other senders launch or control their receiver side, for example Hulu+ may not like it if you wan to write your own app to launch and control that application on your Chromecast; if they decide to allow such model, they need to publish the steps (for example, they can publish their App ID and additional custom data that would link deep into their application). YouTube is no different in that respect.

Comment: Ali, you can absolutely play YouTube videos outside of the YouTube app and that is completely supported. The point of my post is not that but rather a subtle interaction between YouTube and Soundcloud that is causing problems.

Comment: When you say "it is completely supported", do you mean there are Cast APIs in the official SDK to support that? If not, then it is not supported; if yes, which ones are they, since I am not aware of them. In other words, are you using any official Cast SDK apis to launch YouTube and play/control any particular video?

Comment: It's supported in the sense that you are free to use the YouTube v3 iframe api and it works. It is not part of the Chromecast receiver api but it doesn't need to be.